# program "Share with others" in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to program "Share with others" in Google docs through some API/interface etc., Essentially I want to reach out "Email Spreadsheet" or Docs page and utilize its services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible through access control list feeds (ACL).
You can retrieve an ACL feed for any given folder/document/spreadsheet etc, modify it and POST/PUT it back. More info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#AccessControlLists).

There are also libraries for Java and .NET that make it easier. Documentation for Document List API v3.0 isn't up to date for .NET yet though (although the v3.0 code is available in trunk), but for Java there is more info available.

Comment: Thanx for your inputs , what I was requesting was an API call directly to call share with others, give it list of attachments and it goes and does it for me without me downloading any of those attachments/docs